# Send array of images in post request in ios

Tags: swift, image, alamofire

i'm trying to send images in a post request but it isn't going to the server side, i'm doing this using multipart, i don't know why it is happening so and even response is not coming right. this is my code,

```
 func addAPI()
{
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]


    let parameters :[String: Any]  = ["name":productNameTxt.text!,
                                      "price":priceTxt.text!,
                                      "size": sizeTxt.text!,
                                      "weight":weightTxt.text!,
                                      "quality":qualityTxt.text!,
                                      "brand":brandTxt.text!,
                                      "shippingCost":shippingCostTxt.text!,
                                      "details":detailTxt.text!,
                                      "material_id":"\(materialId)",
                                      "material_type_id": "\(subMaterialId)",
                                      "maxQuantity":"4"]

    print(parameters)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let data = ((value) as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)

            }
        }

//            for (index, image) in self.imageArray.enumerated() {
//                multipartFormData.append(image.pngData()!, withName: "file", fileName: "image\(index).png", mimeType: "image/png")
//            }

        for i in 0..<self.imageArray.count{
            let imageData1 = self.imageArray[i].jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)
            multipartFormData.append(imageData1!, withName: "morephoto[\(i)]" , fileName: "photo" + String(i) + ".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    },
                     to: addProductUrl,method:HTTPMethod.post,
                     headers:headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload
                                .validate()
                                .responseJSON { response in
                                    switch response.result {
                                    case .success(let value):
                                      //  compBlock(value as AnyObject,true)
                                        print("responseObject: \(value)")
                                        print(response.data,response.value,response.error)
                                    case .failure(let responseError):
                                        print("responseError: \(responseError)")
                                        print(response.data,response.value,response.error)
                                    }
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print("encodingError: \(encodingError)")
                            let errorDesc = (encodingError as NSError).localizedDescription
                            //failure(errorDesc as NSString,false)
                        }
    })

}
```

whats the mistake i'm making?

Comment: Check the api in Postman

Comment: in postman it's working fine. @RajeshKumarR